# Flutter - getx how to get sub class data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-getx

[image][image]

i am only able to access data from "restaurants" by using getx but after "restaurants" i am unable to access data from "swad"/"menu"/"apple"/data

i want access all data .Not only "apple" but all like "among us","plant",else all.

i previously use streambuilder  .but now i want to use getx to use it in efficient way.

thank you;

Answer (score 0):

By using-- await `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("restaurants").doc("swad").collection("menu").get()`

This code snippet will fetch all documents data like apple amongus and other too

This is async function after you sucessfully fetch data just update the data using the getx using update() function or with .obs functionality

I think this answer will be useful to you. if you any doubts comment below

Answer (score -1):

thank for the replay now i understand the value must be saved before like provider i thought their  is a easy so i asked.

i used get_storage package.
it solved the issue.

box.write('menu', items[index]);
box.read('menu')